# Windows has broken and will not boot nor reinstall, need to install ubuntu. Partition questions

Tags: 12.04

The title explains what has happened. This is on a lenovo Y560P.

Now what I need to know is when I install from the live CD I want format the C drive (We have got all the data) as I do not want to override the lenovo recovery partitions?

Will this play okay with the bootloader?

Or shall I just format the the whole drive? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to erase Windows and install Ubuntu on the whole disk. If that is the case, you can choose "Replace Windows with Ubuntu" and the installer will automatically format the drive for you.

Alternatively, you could choose "Something Else," then manually specify that you want to format the whole disk and use a new partition scheme.

Ubuntu will create a new bootloader partition for itself, so you don't have to explicitly make one with the partitioning tool.

Comment: If I choose the first option will it still play nice with the bootloader and keep recovery partitions? But that sounds like the route I will go down.

Comment: If you mean you need to keep the Windows recovery partitions (the ones that come preloaded on PCs), then you should manually re-partition the disk. Erasing the whole disk would remove everything, and Ubuntu would re-populate with its own files. If you instead choose to manually partition, you can keep the backup partitions the way they are, and re-format just the primary Windows NTFS partition.